# Common way of accessing files

Tags: c#, visual-studio, iis, azure, windows-services

I have projects which:

- use deployed files (i.e. project can send mail using templates deployed with project)
- local files system (i.e. for temp files)

and are running as:

- web app on local IIS
- windows service on local machine
- web role on Azure
- worker role on Azure

Now I have settings with path to deployed and local files and directories, but I have to set sometimes absolute paths (windows service), sometimes relatives (azure web role). Sometimes is hard to say, how path should be set.

Is there any way to have **one** way of setting path? Way, that would work in all above environments?

Answer (score 0):

There's no one single way of accessing files in different environments. When your code runs in Web/Worker role, your application has access to specialized folder (local storage) and you read/write files there. When your code runs as Windows Service on local machine, you could grant access to any folder on that machine (and same goes for web app in local IIS).

I would recommend two options:

1. Abstract File System access and write concrete implementation per environment.
2. Use blob storage if it is possible.

Comment: Even on Azure there is local file system which I want to use.

Comment: With Web/Worker role, unfortunately you don't get access to local file system. Your only option is to use local storage which is a designated part on your local file system. Please read this blog post for more details: http://blog.codingoutloud.com/2011/06/12/azure-faq-can-i-write-to-the-file-system-on-windows-azure/.

Comment: Even in this blog post is written that there is access to local filesystem. I can probably live without temp directory, but I need to access others files from my solution (i.e. templates from project). I don't want to put them to blob - it would be overkill.